# iOS programming: what if I want an ambiguous layout?

Tags: ios

I have a layout with a table view in the middle of the page.  I want that table view to be sized arbitrarily, depending on the screen size of the user's device. In ascii:

```
+-----------+
|some stuff |
+-----------+
|arbitrarily|
|sized stuff|
+-----------+
|other stuff|
+-----------+
```

On a 4 inch screen:

```
+-----------+
|some stuff |
+-----------+
|arbitrarily|
|sized stuff|
|is bigger  |
+-----------+
|other stuff|
+-----------+
```

How can I set up that that arbitrarily sized stuff in the middle is sized appropriately for the user's display, but doesn't return an ambiguous layout warning during compilation?  The stuff, right now, is a table view.

Comment: Well, that's hard to say...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `somestuff` and `otherstuff` both have a fixed height, and all the views have spacing constraints to their immediate neighbors, then the layout should not be ambiguous: the tableview in the middle MUST take all the remaining space in order to fulfill its spacing contraints.

If `somestuff` and `otherstuff` don't have a fixed height but instead rely on their intrinsic content size, I think you can adjust priorities so that the size of the tableview is adjusted properly.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Got it now-- apparently, they also need to have fixed coordinates relative to the edges of the screens.